# Customizing format of float numbering in memoir

Tags: formatting, numbering, memoir

I'm interested in altering the format of float numbers throughout (both in captions and references) in a `memoir` document from the standard **Table 1.1** and **Figure 1.1** to **Table 1-1** and **Figure 1-1** to make the numbering a bit more distinctive compared to header numbering.

I've tried `\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{chapter}--\arabic{figure}}` etc. but this has no effect.

I can find plenty about how to remove the chapter number or add the section, but not how to change the period to something else.

Comment: In a tiny document your command works for me with `memoir`. If you do something different and it does not work, you should post a MWE that shows your setup

Comment: the code you show should be the answer so if it doesn't work some more code you haven't shown is redefining `\thefigure` again.

Comment: I'm guessing there is a `\mainmatter ` in that doc that we cannot see, it resets `\thefigure`, but as always, with no mwe we cannot know for sure.

Comment: @daleif That was the problem!